# What is the purpose of the AttributeKind Group and the AttributeSubKind GroupDepartment in BB10 Cascades?

Tags: blackberry-cascades

Anyone figured it out? I don't see those fields used in the Contacts app, neither does the documentation provide any clue.

```
#include <bb/pim/contacts/AttributeKind>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> A ContactAttribute is a single piece of information about a Contact,
>   such as a phone number or email address. A ContactAttribute has a
>   kind, which specifies high-level metadata about the attribute. Kinds
>   of attributes are represented by the AttributeKind::Type enumeration
>   and include email, phone number, name, and so on. A ContactAttribute
>   also has a sub-kind, which specifies additional, more granular
>   metadata about the attribute. Sub-kinds are represented by the
>   AttributeSubKind::Type enumeration and include values such as Work
>   (for emails), Home (for phone numbers), and so on.

[https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*pim*_contacts__contactattribute.html](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__pim__contacts__contactattribute.html)

Comment: Well, yes, of course, I read that, but what kind of information can I expect to find stored in the Group and SubGroup?